# Mount different shares from nfs on a Linux OS using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have two different shares from nfs and want to mount them on a linux machine. kindly suggest any other possibilities

```
-  name: mount the nfsshare in client side
     mount:
       fstype: nfs
       opts: defaults
       dump: 0
       passno: 0
       state: mounted
       src: 192.168.0.55:/nfsshare       ##one share
       src: 192.168.0.55:/nfsshare_2     ##second share
       path: "{{ item }}"
     with_items:
       - /mnt/nfs_mount               ##mount point 1
       - /mnt/nfs_mount2              ##mount point  2
```

output has to be in fstab:

```
192.168.0.55:/nfsshare  /mnt/nfs_mount defaults 0 0
192.168.0.55:/nfsshare_2  /mnt/nfs_mount_2  defaults 0 0
```

Comment: please format it correclty

Answer (score 5):

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    nfsmounts:
      - {  path: "/mnt/nfs_mount", src: "192.168.0.55:/nfsshare" }
      - {  path: "/mnt/nfs_mount_2", src: "192.168.0.55:/nfsshare_2" }
  tasks:
      - name: mount the nfsshare in client side
        mount:
          fstype: nfs
          opts: defaults
          dump: 0
          passno: 0
          state: mounted
          src: "{{item.src}}"
          path: "{{item.path}}"
        with_items: "{{nfsmounts}}"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

First define your dict:

```
nfsmounts:
  - {  path: "/mnt/nfs_mount", src: "192.168.0.55:/nfsshare" }
  - {  path: "/mnt/nfs_mount_2", src: "192.168.0.55:/nfsshare_2" }
```

Then loop through it:

```
-  name: mount the nfsshare in client side
     mount:
       fstype: nfs
       opts: defaults
       dump: 0
       passno: 0
       state: mounted
       src: {{ item.src }}
       path: "{{ item.path }}"
     with_items: nfsmounts
```

You can use the dic to parametrize more arguments of `mount` task too if you want

Comment: You are welcome, if you found the answer useful, to accept or upvote it.